# Assigning a new value to a python variable

Tags: python

I'm extremely new to Python and working on my first text-based game. In this game, I would like player to choose from a list of characters. In the course of the game, I would also like to give the player the ability to change the character (which ultimately affects the outcome of the game). I'm unable to understand what I need to do to ensure the new choice of character is saved appropriately. Below is a stripped down version of the code:

```
def identity_choice():
    identity = input("""Your options are:
    1.  Ordinary Tourist
    2.  Chef
    Please choose a number""")
    if identity == "1":
        print("You now look like a tourist!")
        return identity
    elif identity == "2":
        print("You are now a chef")
        return identity
    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand that.")
        return identity_choice()

def action(identity):
    if identity == "1":
        print("You can't do what you need to as a tourist")
        response = input("Would you like to change your disguise?")
        if "y" in response:
            identity_choice()
        else:
            print("You have chosen to retain your identity")

identity = identity_choice()

action(identity)
```

Comment: What's wrong in your code? Does it not run as expected? please provide sample expected ouput

Comment: Perhaps return the result of `identity_choice` when you call it from `action`, and assign it to the global `identity`?  Alternatively, wrap all of this in a `class` and make `identity` a member of the class, so that both of these functions have the ability to change it.

Comment: Your function action needs to return identy. And then  identity = action(identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

All you need to do is reassign the `identity` variable, if this is the way you are choosing to keep track of the players identity. For example:

`if "y" in response:
     identity = identity_choice()`

After this you can `return identity` if you would like, or you may, as the other answer suggested, declare `global identity` inside the `action` function description. This way, the `identity` variable is shared throughout the entire script.

**Longer Answer**

Actually won't be that long, but this seems like a great place to learn some object oriented programming. You stated that you're just starting, so if it's too early, then don't bother just yet, you'll get there!

However, a nice way to set this up could be to instantiate users as an object of some class, such as `user`, and then this class could either have a second class `identity` which inherits from the `user` class. Or, the `user` class could simply have a variable called `identity`, which can be changed with a simple function. Here is a very brief and incomplete example:

```
class user:
    def __init__(self):
        pass   # here you could call the choose identity function, or just 
               # initialize with some default identity
    def choose_identity():
        #the function you wrote above asking the user to choose their identity
```

Hope this helps a bit, I tried to keep it very simple

Comment: This was extremely helpful and worked perfectly. Thanks very much. Object oriented programming is the next part of the course, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The variable "identity" is used only local to the function(s). If you need the variable global, just declare the variable outside all functions, and inside the functions you enter the line "global identity".

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you mean.
I assume that the problem is in the "action(identity)" function that the new identity is not saved in case the user chooses "y".
Change it into:

```
def action(identity):
   if identity == "1":
      print("You can't do what you need to as a tourist")
      response = input("Would you like to change your disguise?")
   if "y" in response:
      return identity_choice()
   else:
      print("You have chosen to retain your identity")
      return identity
```

Then, when you call action, do it like this:

```
identity = action(identity)
```